# Method Parameter Annotations in overridden methods

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Is there any way to get the parameter annotations of a method in child class? I tried using the [getParameterAnnotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getParameterAnnotations()) but it not works. I wrote a test class to demonstrate:

```
public class ParameterAnnotationInheritanceTest {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
    @Inherited
    public @interface MockAnnotation {

    }

    public class A {

        public void test(@MockAnnotation String value) {

        }
    }

    public class B extends A {

        @Override
        public void test(String value) {

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void TestA() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Method AMethod = A.class.getMethod("test", String.class);
        Annotation[][] AMethodParameterAnnotations = AMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(AMethodParameterAnnotations[0]).size() > 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void TestB() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        Method BMethod = B.class.getMethod("test", String.class);
        Annotation[][] BMethodParameterAnnotations = BMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
        assertTrue(Arrays.asList(BMethodParameterAnnotations[0]).size() > 0);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because the test method in the child class B is not the same test method as in the super class. By overriding it, you have practically defined a new test method that gets called instead of the original one. If you define your child class like this

```
public class B extends A {

}
```

and run your code again, it works fine because it is the inherited test method that gets called, which is what you want as far as I understand.

Comment: Hi Kateriana. thanks for your answer. The method must be overridden the method because i need to add some annotations to the method himself in child class, i want a way to inherit the parameter annotations. But I understood why it can not be done.

Comment: Hi Thiago. Please mark it as the correct answer to your question if that is the case ;-)